# curl error : error initializing curl library Windows Server 2016

Tags: curl

recently I have problem with curl, any command I execute I got same error `error initializing curl library`, I'm running Windows Server 2016, on `cmd` any command I use I have same error, but in `powershell` when I run `curl --help`, I I got the error that says `can not resolve host --help`

I'm trying to config an run `couchdb` but when I execute this command `curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/` on powershell, I got an error like this: 
`A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.`

I already download the binaries from [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and add a environment variable to system setting

am I missing somthing?

I add an image of getting errors: [image: errors]

Comment: I am facing the same error as in your `cmd` example using `Git Bash`. I think the powershell output differs because `curl` is just an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, which apparently does not support the `--help` parameter. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Windows Updates

- KB4103723
- KB4093137
- KB890830
- KB4103329

fixed the problem for me. I don't know which of those updates could be responsible for this though.